# how to select which property in my model convert to json result. asp.net mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

i have Product model and this have many property.

```
public class Product
{
   public int ID{get; set;}
   public string Title{get; set;}     
   public int Count{get; set;}
   public Group_cls Group{get; set;}
   public X x{get; set;}
   public Y y{get; set;}
}
```

but when i want convert that to json( using controller.json(list of product) method) just need some property (example: ID,Title,Count).

```
{
       {
          ID : 1,
          title : 'title1',
           count : 5
       },
       {
          ID : 2,
          title : 'title2',
           count : 5
       },
       .
       .
       .

}
```

i want that for more security and more performance.
how can i do that? please give me a solution

Comment: Just pass an anonymous object containing the properties you need in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke in fact, i have list of product so i think converting to anonymous object have cost

Comment: Of course not - `var data = db.Products.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Title = x.Title }); return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Tanks ,now i got it